# Return an array of matched items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have [This HTML struct](http://codepen.io/Ghaleon/pen/JYXEQa?editors=101) there you will see this table:

```
<table class="col-md-6 table" id="prof-table">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <th>HORÁRIO</th>
                    <th data-dia="seg">Segunda-Feira</th>
                    <th data-dia="ter">Terça-Feira</th>
                    <th data-dia="qua">Quarta-Feira</th>
                    <th data-dia="qui">Quinta-Feira</th>
                    <th data-dia="sex">Sexta-Feira</th>                 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>08:30 ~ 10:30</td>
                <td>
                   <ol>
                     <li data-prof="3">Lab I</li>
                   </ol>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>10:30 ~ 12:30</td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                   <ol>
                      <li data-prof="3">Lab II</li>
                   </ol>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>14:30 ~ 16:30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>16:30 ~ 18:30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>18:30 ~ 20:30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>20:30 ~ 21:30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>21:30 ~ 23:30</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
```

I need to get an array / collection of all `<li>` inside a specific `<td>`, I have done this:

```
var $items = $(myRow).find('ol > li');                                  
   $.each($items, function(){
      if($(this).text() == disciplina){
         if($(this).data('prof') != professor_id){
            $(myRow).find('td > ol').append("<li data-prof='"+professor_id+"'>"+            disciplina +"</li>");
      }
   }

});
```

But `$items` returns me a single `<li>` element for each iteration, what if I want an array with all the `<li>` at once ? How may I do that?

Comment: All the `td` elements only contain one `li`, so I'm unclear as to the behaviour you're expecting

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It's just an example, there will have more than one.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the specific route you can use that:

```
$("td > ol > li")
```

Or more generic:

```
$("td").find("li")
```